# d3 path d = MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

Trying to build a linechart (multiple lines). Initial data has been an array of object such as:

```
[{
    2010: 8236.082,
    countryName: "Afghanistan"
}]
```

Each line required an array of x/y pairs `[[x,y],[x,y]]`. My `x` and `y` are `year` and `amount` of emissions. This means I had to restructure my data it to make it look like this:

```
[
     {
         country: "Afganistan",
         emissions: [
             { year: 2019, amount: 8236.082 }
         ]
     }
]
```

After data munging I'm stuck with path d = MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN. What am I doing wrong here?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/edgarkiljak/pen/JeXXdV)

```
//Define full width, full height and margins
let fullWidth = 600;
let fullHeight = 700;
let margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 70,
    bottom: 100,
    right: 10
}

//Define line chart with and height 
let width = fullWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = fullHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Define x and y scale range
let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, height])

//Draw svg
let svg = d3.select("body")
    .attr("width", fullWidth)
    .attr("height", fullHeight)
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/izmg6").then(data => {
    console.log(data);



    //Structure data so should be an array of arrays  etc [[x,y], [x,y], [x,y]]

    let years = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(0, 50);
    console.log(years);

    let dataset = [];

    data.forEach((d, i) => {

        let myEmissions = [];

        years.forEach(y => {
            if (d[y]) {

                myEmissions.push({
                    year: y,
                    amount: d[y]
                })
            }
        })

        dataset.push({
            country: d.countryName,
            emissions: myEmissions
        });
    })

    console.log(dataset);

    //Define x and y domain
    xScale
        .domain(d3.extent(years))

    yScale
        .domain([d3.max(dataset, d =>
        d3.max(d.emissions, d =>
            +d.amount)), 0])


        //Generate line
    let line = d3.line()
                .x(d => {
                    xScale(d.year);
                })
                .y(d => {
                    yScale(d.amount);
                });


    let groups = d3.selectAll("g")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

    groups.append("title")
        .text(d => d.country)

    groups.selectAll("path")
        .data(d => [d.emissions])
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("class", line)

}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Where are you seeing a bunch of NaN values?

Comment: @Amy If you go to the codepen and inspect the output window, the SVG consists of groups of paths with NaNs.

Comment: One thing, unrelated, it looks like your groups of paths are being appended outside of your SVG.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge Ah, it took a bit of searching but I finally see them.  Thanks. 
 `document.querySelectorAll("g > path")`

Comment: @PeterCollingridge thanks has to be groups = svg.selectAll("g")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of the NaN is

```
let line = d3.line()
   .x(d => xScale(d.year) )
   .y(d => yScale(d.amount) );
```

But that is not the only problem of the chart.

Comment: Thanks d path now has values. Would you please be able to guide me what else is wrong?

Comment: What was the error in the above code snippet?

Comment: @AntonioRiccelli you get a `NaN` as the result of a scale call when you feed it incorrect arguments or at the scale construction, so check the values you want to scale and convert if needed at the scale call and also when constructing the scale. The json file is no longer to fetch, but his example is incorrect

Comment: Thank you @rioV8 - I don't suppose I could ask for your help? I'm struggling with a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351488/react-d3-js-density-plot-error-path-attribute-d-expected-number-m10-na) 

I do think there's something wrong with the scale, but I haven't managed to figure it out...